# Can't link against static library when compiling objects from LLVM bitcode.

Tags: c, llvm, clang

I am developing an LLVM compiler pass. I run a pass in the following way:

1. Compile to LLVM bitcode

   ```
   clang  foo.c -emit-llvm -c -o foo.bc
   ```
2. Run foo.bc through opt (The error still occurs without this step)
3. Compile back to an object file

   ```
   clang  -c -o foo.o foo.bc
   ```
4. Now foo.o might be part of a static library.

   ```
   ar rc libfoo.a foo.o
   ```
5. **I am unable to link against libfoo.a when all my c files are compiled in this way.**

   ```
   clang libfoo.a linkme.o -o linkme

   linkme.o:linkme.bc:function main: error: undefined reference to 'foo'
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   ```

Source files:

foo.c:

```
int foo(int a)
{
    return a;
}
```

foo.h

```
int foo(int a);
```

linkme.c

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   foo(6);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try create an index for libfoo.a using ranlib.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now I feel silly. It has nothing to do with the .bc files, just the ordering of the arguments.

Works:

```
clang  linkme.o  libfoo.a -o linkme
```

Fails:

```
clang  libfoo.a linkme.o -o linkme
```