# Is it possible to link bitcode with llvm-ar archieve into a single bitcode file?

Tags: c, linker, clang, llvm

I have read [this thread](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2013-February/059759.html) on llvm-dev and is faced with the same problem: I cannot link the **llvm-ar** archieve library with other **bitcode** files into another single **bitcode file** with the help of `llvm-link`.

```
clang -emit-llvm -g -c -o main.bc main.c
clang -emit-llvm -g -c -o calc.bc calc.c
llvm-ar rcs libcalc.la calc.bc
llvm-link libcalc.la main.bc -o test
```

the problem is the same: `llvm-link` complains

```
llvm-link: libcalc.la:1:2: error: expected integer
!<arch>
 ^
```

And after reading [How to link object to libraries with LLVM >= 3.1 ? ( no GNU ld )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528474/how-to-link-object-to-libraries-with-llvm-3-1-no-gnu-ld), I also tried a llvm2.9 version of **llvm-ld**.

```
llvm-ld --disable-opt libcalc.la main.bc -o test
```

however `libcalc.la` is *not* linked into the module correctly and `lli` reports:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'Square' which could not be resolved!
```

So what should i do?

**UPDATE**

I then read [Can't link against static library when compiling objects from LLVM bitcode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613091/cant-link-against-static-library-when-compiling-objects-from-llvm-bitcode?rq=1) and find that **llvm-ld** WORKS when changing the order:

```
llvm-ld --disable-opt  main.bc libcalc.la -o test
```

But `llvm-link` still fails.

Comment: You can use gold LTO plugin - there is an option to keep a combined IR file.

Comment: @SK-logic Thanks. But what's the exact option then? Seems that llvm documentation(http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html) contains so little about it.

Comment: It is called `also-emit-llvm`

Comment: Thanks, is there any document about it? I am not familiar with ld options.

Comment: Use it as "-plugin-opt=also-emit-llvm"

Comment: @SK-logic I mean, how can I get all the options available for a plugin library if I use `ld --plugin xxx.so`, `ld --plugin xxx.so --help` doesn't produce `-plugin-opt` for xxx.so.

Comment: I do not think it's possible to get a list of plugin options. There is no such interface for plugins.

Comment: @SK-logic That's a pity. And you got this option from llvm source code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `llvm-link` does not support bitcode archives, AFAIK. It simply goes over the input files it was provided, and tries to parse each one as a bitcode file (either binary or textual LLVM IR).
- `llvm-ld` doesn't exist in the newer LLVMs, so I would suggest to stay away from it completely.

Just link the separate `.bc` files together with `llvm-link`. The archiving of bitcode files doesn't have the same benefits for the linker as in native linking anyway.

Comment: Maybe there is a need to tweak llvm-link a bit to work like the old `llvm-ld`? We are dealing with a huge library and we would like to archieve the bitcode; otherwise it would be troublesome to link the objects manually.

Comment: @HongxuChen: you can suggest to llvmdev@ to provide a patch that lets `llvm-link` read archives :-) Moreover, note that it's a very minimal and small tool and it's trivial to implement its functionality (including enhancements) on your own

Answer (score -1):

You don't need archivers to link your bitcode files:

```
clang -emit-llvm -g -c -o main.bc main.c
clang -emit-llvm -g -c -o calc.bc calc.c
clang main.bc calc.bc -o test
```